# How exactly does `dnf install 'pkgconfig(NAME)'` syntax work?

Tags: packaging, pkg-config, dnf

[Fedora Packaging Guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/PkgConfigBuildRequires/) ([permalink](https://web.archive.org/web/20230324060022/https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/PkgConfigBuildRequires/)) officially recommends using the `pkgconfig(NAME)` syntax when declaring build dependencies. So for example, instead of `BuildRequires: libxcb-devel`, you would declare `BuildRequires: pkgconfig(xcb)`. (Similarly, `dnf install 'pkgconfig(xcb)'` would offer to install `libxcb-devel`, which is why I assumed this is a feature of `dnf` as opposed to the SPEC file processor.)

I've always been curious, and honestly it has bugged me throughout these few years I've been doing packaging - how exactly does this work? I know `pkg-config` (or `pkgconf`) uses `.pc` files to determine a library's associated names and arguments, and that those `.pc` files are shipped with development libraries (`*-devel` packages on Fedora). But that's the problem - how does the build system (more specifically, `dnf`) resolve a declaration like `pkgconfig(xcb)` before installing `libxcb-devel` which provides the `.pc` file?

The only possible explanation I can think of at this point is if there's some kind of central registry of all `.pc` files within the remote repositories that `dnf` can easily query. But I can find absolutely no documentation for this, nor have I noticed the existence of such a file in various mirrors.

So what kind of magic is `dnf install pkgconfig(NAME)` doing? Is there a map (or a command to compute a map) between `pkgconfig(NAME)` and the concrete packages they point to? This would make the process of looking up the right name to declare in `BuildRequires:` a whole lot easier for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I did some digging, and it turns out the `pkgconfig(...)` entries are listed as "provides" entries in the package metadata. Therefore there is not really anything special with the `pkgconfig(...)` syntax; it's just another string in the eyes of dnf. In fact, a quick search in the [dnf repository](https://github.com/rpm-software-management/dnf) returns nothing at all:

```bash
$ rg 'pkg-?conf(ig)?'
# nothing printed
```

---

During package build, it seems like `rpmbuild` will look for all `*.pc` files declared by the spec file, and generate corresponding `pkgconfig(...)` provides entries. Those entries are stored in the package metadata, which means they are trivially queryable even before installing the package.

To list the items provided by a package, run:

```bash
$ dnf repoquery --provides <PKG>

# for example (bzip2-devel, RHEL8)
$ dnf repoquery --provides bzip2-devel
bzip2-devel = 1.0.6-26.el8
bzip2-devel(x86-32) = 1.0.6-26.el8
bzip2-devel(x86-64) = 1.0.6-26.el8
pkgconfig(bzip2) = 1.0.6
```

To list the packages that provide an item, run:

```bash
$ dnf provides <ITEM>

# for example (pkgconfig(bzip2), RHEL8)
# note that parentheses need to be either quoted or escaped
# see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26064/375550
$ dnf provides 'pkgconfig(bzip2)'
bzip2-devel-1.0.6-26.el8.i686 : Libraries and header files for apps which will use bzip2
Repo        : rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Matched from:
Provide    : pkgconfig(bzip2) = 1.0.6

bzip2-devel-1.0.6-26.el8.x86_64 : Libraries and header files for apps which will use bzip2
Repo        : rhel-8-for-x86_64-baseos-rpms
Matched from:
Provide    : pkgconfig(bzip2) = 1.0.6
```